# ¿Cómo hago un programa experto con Árboles en C++?

Tags: c++, clase, árboles

Quiero realizar un programa que pueda determinar si debes hacer tu servicio militar dados tu género, tu edad, estado de salud, etc. usando árboles (con class) me cuesta mucho manejarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow, tu pregunta es demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio y seguramente será puesta en espera. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento de StackOverflow, y a visitar el [centro de ayuda](/help) donde encontrarás información sobre lo que puedes y no preguntar aquí.

Comment: tengo tantas ganas de explotar, no importa al final del día termina siendo solo una simple pregunta mal hecha, ignora lo primero, primero te puedo recomendar que aprendas orientado a objetos de dicho lenguaje, y luego que revises el centro de ayuda que te indica @jachguate - Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas.
Tu pregunta es muy amplia. Pero aún así la técnica que buscas se llama [Arboles de Desición](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol_de_decisi%C3%B3n) para lo que también existe un método de aprendizaje automático llamado [Aprendizaje basado en arboles de decisión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprendizaje_basado_en_%C3%A1rboles_de_decisi%C3%B3n).

Para esto existen distintos algoritmos que son mas o menos complejos de implementar. Los mas conocidos son:

- [Algoritmo ID3](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_ID3)
- [Algoritmo C4.5](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5)

Te recomiendo que busques el tema en inglés, en sitios como GitHub para encontrar ejemplos de implementaciones. (EJ: [Proyecto relacionado en Github](https://github.com/bonz0/Decision-Tree)

Tambien puedes hacer uso de software de análisis como [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/). Hay bastantes tutoriales en la red.